# django csv header and row format problem

Tags: python, django, csv, django-views, export-to-csv

I am trying to create csv download ,but result download gives me in different format

```
def csv_download(request):
    import csv
    import calendar
    from datetime import *
    from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

    now=datetime.today()
    month = datetime.today().month
    d = calendar.mdays[month]

    # Create the HttpResponse object with the appropriate CSV header.
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=somefilename.csv'
    m=Product.objects.filter(product_sellar = 'jhon')
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(['S.No'])
    writer.writerow(['product_name'])
    writer.writerow(['product_buyer'])
    for i in xrange(1,d):

       writer.writerow(str(i) + "\t")



    for f in m:
         writer.writerow([f.product_name,f.porudct_buyer])

    return response
```

output of above code :

```
product_name
1
2
4
5
6
7
8
9
1|10
1|1
1|2
.
.
.
2|7


mgm | x_name
wge | y_name
```

I am looking out put like this

```
s.no   porduct_name product_buyser  1     2   3   4   5   6   7   8 9 10 .....27 total
  1   mgm            x_name         2      3      8                                13
  2  wge             y_name                   4       9                            13
```

can you please help me with above csv download ?
if possible can you please tell me how to sum up all the individual  user total at end?

Example :

we have selling table in that every day  seller info will be inserted

table data looks like

```
 S.no product_name product_seller sold Date
  1     paint        jhon           5   2011-03-01
  2     paint        simth          6   2011-03-02
```

I have created a table where it displays below format and i am trying to create csv download

```
s.no prod_name   prod_sellar 1-03-2011  2-03-2011   3-03-2011   4-03-2011 total
    1     paint         john       10        15               0               0     25
    2     paint         smith      2          6               2               0     10
```

Comment: What other fields does the product object have? You're only exposing product_name and product_buyer in your sample code above.

Comment: are you just generating the file for a specific month determined before you get objects from the database?

Comment: yes,i am trying to generate a for a  specific month

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [csv module documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html), particularly the [writer object API](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#writer-objects).

You'll notice that the csv.writer object takes a list with elements representing their position in your delimited line. So to get the desired output, you would need to pass in a list like so:

```
writer = csv.writer(response)
writer.writerow(['S.No', 'product_name', 'product_buyer'] + range(1, d) + ['total'])
```

This will give you your desired header output.

You might want to explore the [csv.DictWriter](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) class if you want to only populate some parts of the row. It's much cleaner. This is how you would do it:

```
writer = csv.DictWriter(response, 
                        ['S.No', 'product_name', 'product_buyer'] + range(1, d) + ['total'])
```

Then when your write command would follow as so:

```
for f in m:
    writer.writerow({'product_name': f.product_name, 'product_buyer': f.product_buyer})
```

Comment: thank you for the code,here i am unable to get the data according the date,like range(1,d) r like dates header and depends on the i need to pull data according to that cell..

Comment: Can you give me an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: i have added example to question